# Black Pixel in imagecopyresampled ( png ) PHP

Tags: php

I have a script that I think is correct, but when I see the results of the script, there is a black section below each additional image, even though the image is transparent (png)

```
header('Content-type: image/png');

$path = "https://example.com/imagecopy/";
$im1 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'background.png');
$im2 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'Player1.png');

imagecopyresampled($im1,$im2,0,935,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im2);

$im3 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'Player2.png');
imagecopyresampled($im1,$im3,103,832,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im3);

$im4 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'Player3.png');
imagecopyresampled($im1,$im4,207,728,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im4);

$im5 = imagecreatefrompng($path.'Player4.png');
imagecopyresampled($im1,$im5,313,624,0,0,100,150,100,150);
unset($im5);
imagealphablending($im1, false);

imagepng($im1);
```

[Example player1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCq9X.png)

This is the picture of the result (look at the top of numbers 2, 18 and 24):

[image]

are there any shortcomings of my script? all the images above are 100% png and transparent except background.png

Comment: Can you post the original image? Might be useful for reference.

Comment: I can only provide player1.png images, for other images like the background I can't upload them

Comment: comment out some of the `imagecopyresampled` lines and see which one makes the black boxes disappear?